# Reading Excel file Issue from another directory Python

Tags: python, pandas

guys.

I'm having an issue reading a excel file from another directory.
My code is the following:

```
failures = pd.read_excel(r'./../Análise/ASR - Análise Falhas.xlsx', sheet_name='Eventos_2021')
```

The error I'm getting is:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './../Análise/ASR - Análise Falhas.xlsx'

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the file opened when you run it? Make sure to close it

Comment: Yep, it was and it worked.... sorry lol